# Collecting touch events outside of android app

Tags: android, touch

I'm currently working on an app that requires collecting of sensory data, system information, etc, including touch events. I specifically only need to collect information from ACTION_DOWN.

I can easily implement this within the app's activity/view, but I'm having issues collecting outside of the app itself. I've found conflicting information about this so far, ranging from it being possible to collect ACTION_OUTSIDE events only, to it being completely impossible due to touch-jacking security issues.

Past solutions I've found at most have been able to accomplish this by creating some type of overlay, but fail to pass on the touch after collecting it, effectively making the phone un-usable.

If someone could point me in the right direction on this, or at least clarify that it is indeed impossible it would be greatly appreciated. The main reason I'm creating my own question for this is to get an up to date answer on this topic, as I realize functionality changes very rapidly, and most of the topics about this I've found are from at least 3 years ago